# Sum of product of positive matrices

Tags: symmetric-matrices

Let $A,B$ be two positive hermitian matrices in $M_n(\mathbb{C})$.

Is $AB+BA$ a positive hermitian matrix ?

This is almost the same question as [Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/943049/sum-of-products-of-positive-operators), but it seems to me the response was not entirely complete. Is there a classical example of a product of two positive matrices that is not accretive ?

Is there a condition, apart from the commutativity, that would ensure the result ?

Comment: Yes $(AB+BA)^* = AB+BA$

Comment: @MustadaSaid That only checks hermiticity. Also, $\ast$ should be $\dagger$.

Comment: Indeed, the question is more about positivity than hermiticity. I thougt that maybe someone had a classical couterexample. I will try to construct one myself.